# How to download multiples file in background and update corresponding progressview

Tags: asynchronous, ios7, background, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I am using NSURLSession to download files in background ..I have seen [this](https://github.com/ncipollina/nsurlsession-sample)

link and it is working fine .But i have to download multiple files ,Like the image i uploaded.

How to achieve this ,any advise would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Block Coding

```
  typedef void (^onDownload)(NSData *data);
typedef void (^onDownloadProgress)(id,id);

@property (nonatomic,retain) onDownload block;
@property (nonatomic,retain) onDownloadProgress progressBlock;
```

**Downloading**

```
 -(void) downloadFileFromURL:(NSURL *)url1 withCompletionBlock:(onDownload)completeBlock withProgressBlock:(onDownloadProgress) pBlock{
    self.block = [completeBlock copy];
    self.progressBlock = [pBlock copy];
    self.url = url1;
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1] delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{
            float progress = (totalBytesWritten *100)/totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
             self.progressBlock(self,[NSNumber numberWithDouble:progress]);
            //return process
    }
```

**Request URL**

```
FileDownloader *download=[[FileDownloader alloc]init];

    [download downloadFileFromURL:url withCompletionBlock:^(NSData *data) {
        [lblProcess setHidden:YES];

      //Compale Dwonloading

    } withProgressBlock:^(FileDownloader *download,NSNumber* process) {
        lblProcess.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%",[process doubleValue]];
    }];
```

Comment: no it will be work in background mode not when app is in background state

Comment: how to achieve this kind of functionality when app is in background any idea